# Does it make a sense to install final release instead of beta 2?

Tags: 11.04, upgrade

I'm not sure if it is better to install final release after it officially ready (or week later when most problems fixed) or it is OK to have patched beta? I think that new is better than patched old, am I right?

Comment: I had beta 1 and my indicator weather disappeared, some screenlets where blinking and I couldn't make it back to work, but when I made fresh install of beta 2 everything started to work fine. (may be it is not related to one another, but looks like it is for me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no difference if you upgrade or install the final version from scratch; if it works now and you want to install it now then go for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed Ubuntu from say alpha/beta and you have steadily downloaded and installed the updates then you won't need to reinstall it as you will be fully up-to-date and will have the final version.

Answer (score 0):

You are encouraged to use beta version as the more people will use it the more robust would be the final version. 
"A stitch in time saves nine", So even just 1 day left in final release of Ubuntu still if you can find any (small) bug it can be patched before final release. 
Go for Beta!! and you can upgrade beta as soon as it is launched. The only problem you may have to face is when you do not have unlimited internet plan and you have to pay for each byte you are downloading just like me :(.